# The facebook lib react-native-fbsdk doesn't work

Tags: facebook, react-native

I tried to change the version of react, but I did not succeed. I already followed several tutorials but I have not been able to solve them yet. Can anybody help me ?

The only files I modified were MainApplication.java and MainActivity.java

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question by pasting a formatted error instead of screenshots. Regarding your errors, they seem related to **Android X**.

Make sure you followed all the steps to migrate to 0.60.0. You can't just change the versions of a lib. You need to read the changelogs and adapt your whole source code.

You can find everything you need to change using the [upgrade-helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.9&to=0.60.0).

See

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and the usage of `jetify`.